# string::erase() gives different result in linux/windows

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code which reads in a line from a file, then removes the whitespace and tells you the length of the string. In windows it works as I expect it to, however in linux it returns a different result.

Code:

```
    // Find how many characters are in the first line
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream map ("level1.map");

    getline(map,line);

    // Remove whitespace from the string to get the useful length of line
    for ( unsigned int i = 0, j ; i < line.length( ) ; ++ i )
    {
        if ( line [i] == ' ' )
        {
            for ( j = i + 1; j < line.length ( ) ; ++j )
            {
                if ( line [j] != ' ' )
                    break ;
            }

            cout << j;
            line = line.erase ( i, (j - i) ) ;
        }
    }

   // Output
   cout << line.size() << endl;
```

It's essentially just trying to determine how many tile columns there are in the map file, where the map is formatted thusly on each line:

2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2

And so whitespace needs to be removed.

In windows given an initial line length of 160 the end length is 80, however when compiled in linux the initial length is 160, but the end length is 81. The only place the value becomes different appears to be after line = line.erase ( i, (j - i) ) ;

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: what is the loop counter when you see the discrepancy?

Comment: A little OT, but: If the lines can be long, this code will be terribly slow because `s.erase(a, b)` performs a number of operations that is proportional to `s.size() - b`. What about just _counting_ the number of contiguous whitespace sequences?

Comment: On a line with 80 non space characters, i appears to skip directly from 79 to 81 in the loop counter

Comment: The idiomatic way of erasing a value from a container (or string) is: `line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ' '), line.end());`. - Also, if there's only one space and each number is single digit, then the number of digits is `(line.size() + 1) / 2`. - Also you can count the digits: `std::count_if(line.begin(), line.end(), &::isdigit);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think therefromhere is right.  The solution is two-fold:

1. Always set the `binary` flag when constructing an [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ifstream/) or `ofstream`.  Let your code handle newlines however it wants, but don't rely on non-portable newline conversion.
2. Choose a standard format (LF or CRLF) for the tile map, and output that format on all platforms.

Then, it will work the same provided you're testing with the same `level1.map`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd hazard a guess that this is related to the different newline markers on Unix/Linux (`\n`) vs DOS/Windows (`\r\n`).